# Sensing motions while phone is in portrait mode

Tags: android, motion

I want to make an android app which needs to listen to the phones motions. I want to listen from the following two states.

In my app the phone needs to be in this position:

[image]

and after the change:

If the screen is up to the sky than call a method and if the screen is down than another method...

[image]

Right now I have the following:

```
 @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        mGravity = event.values.clone();
        // Shake detection
        float x = mGravity[0];
        float y = mGravity[1];
        float z = mGravity[2];
        Log.d("X",String.valueOf(x));
        Log.d("y",String.valueOf(y));
        Log.d("z",String.valueOf(z));
        mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
        mAccelCurrent = FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
        float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
        mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;
        // Make this higher or lower according to how much
        // motion you want to detect
        Log.d("MACCEL",String.valueOf(mAccel));
        if(mAccel > 3){
            // do something
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: First, you should include your images with your post; and not make folks go offsite for them. Second, you stated what you want to do, but you did not ask a question. Where - exactly - are you having problems, and what is(are) your question(s)?

Comment: I dont know where to start :)

Comment: I was wrong about the images. Because you have fewer than 10 points, you can't include them. I'll fix these for you. Be sure to start including images when you get over 10 points :) Sorry about that.

Comment: I know , Thank you ! :) somebody something for my "Question" ?:)

Answer (score 1):

if i get it right, you are talking about detect any shake event in that case you need implement SensorListener and add what ever actions you want in onSensorChange() method

Comment: I have updated the post, i have there that method.. but i dont know what to do next...